# foreign key shall automatically create a new entry

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables `users` and `iom`.
Primary key of `users` is `iomid` and of course in `iom` the foreign key is `iomid` that references users.iomid.

If i create a new user in users, I want it automatically inserted into iom aswell without making a second statement.

How can I do it?

iom:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `iom` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `iomid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `subscribed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `workoutcounter` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `iom`
 ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`), ADD KEY `iom_ibfk_1` (`iomid`);

ALTER TABLE `iom`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `iom`
ADD CONSTRAINT `iom_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`iomid`) REFERENCES `users` (`iomid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

user:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `iomid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `users`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`iomid`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Thanks and greetings!

Comment: You can use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Comment: But I'm not sure how you would get the new user's `iomid` to use in the new `iom` row.

Comment: @Barmar I guess you mean `AFTER INSERT`, since `users.iomid` is  referenced.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel No, I mean `BEFORE`, because the `INSERT` will fail if the foreign key doesn't exist in the referenced table.

Comment: Oh, wait, I read it backwards. I thought he wanted to create a new `user` when creating the referencing `iom`.

Comment: Klaxx, as you can see above, your naming conventions are very very misleading; typically a table's "id" PK is table_id, making other table's references to it a little more self-documenting; you've completely turned that practice upside down.

Comment: It would help to post the create statements for the tables.

Comment: Please add the DDL, so any of us can really understand what you want. Please!

Comment: I edited my question with my create statements. I hope someone can help me. Greetings and thanks already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I look at your question again, the issues with your foreign key conventions are fairly irrelevant. Even with more typical relations, foreign key constraints cannot create rows; at most, they can "cascade" updates and deletes of referenced values to referencing tables.

What you need is an "AFTER INSERT ON users" **trigger**. (Documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).)